# Why in Javascript RegExp have a double Object prototype

Tags: javascript, regex, prototype

I'm very interested about that a regex have a double prototype chain related to the Object "class".

```
//object Object --> Object --> Null
var regex = (/checking\sprototypes/gmi);
console.log(toString.call(regex.__proto__.__proto__.__proto__));
```

Why happen this?

when I print `regex.__proto__` I get the "Object prototype" instead RegExp prototype. If I print `regex.__proto__.__proto__` i get the "Object prototype" too.

Check this codepen for more examples http://codepen.io/gpincheiraa/pen/pEydja

Comment: Because they inherit from `RegExp.prototype`, not from `Object.prototype`? An array instance `[]` or some `new ArbitraryCustomConstructor()` has a prototype chain of the same length btw.

Comment: Btw, `__proto__` is deprecated, you should be using `Object.getPrototypeOf` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Inheritance in JavaScript is not built on *classes*, but on *prototypes*. Object prototypes expose properties and methods available to other objects based on these prototypes, and can be chained in a hierarchy.

```
regex.__proto__;                    // RegExp prototype
regex.__proto__.__proto__           // Object prototype
regex.__proto__.__proto__.__proto__ // null
```

What can be observed here is that a regular expression has a prototype, which is the `RegExp` prototype, exposing regular expression specific methods like `exec` and `test`. The `RegExp` prototype in turn is based on the `Object` prototype, which exposes methods and properties common to (almost) all objects, like `hasOwnProperty` or the `__proto__` getter itself. The `Object` prototype is the top of the hierarchy and has no prototype (`null`).

Comment: So JS classes are "unreal"? :-P

Comment: you say "What can be observed here is that a regular expression has a prototype, which is the RegExp prototype": when I print  `regex.__proto__` i get the "Object prototype" instead  RegExp prototype. If i print `regex.__proto__.__proto__` i get the  "Object prototype" too. check this http://codepen.io/gpincheiraa/pen/pEydja?editors=0010. My question is **why regexp have a double chain to Object prototype?**

Comment: @GonzaloPincheiraArancibia if you run `console.log(regex.__proto__.constructor.name)` you can see that it prints `RegExp`. Also, `regex.__proto__ === RegExp.prototype` evaluates to `true`.